# leaflet integration with openweathermap api

Tags: leaflet, mapquest, openweathermap

[Kindly check my output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkxFb.jpg) Can anybody here help me out with some good tutorial or ways to integrate openweathermap api with leaflet mapquest api. I read on owm website that both are compatible and can work together. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks !

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.0.0/mapquest.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.0.0/mapquest.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        L.mapquest.key = 'mapquestkeyhere';

        var map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
          center: [40.7128, -74.0059],
          layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('map'),
          zoom: 11,

        });
        var latlong = [
                        [40.783060, -73.971249],
                        [40.7128, -74.0059],
                        [40.678178, -73.944158]
                       ];
        var infowindow = ["Manhattan","NY","Brooklyn"];

        for(var i = 0; i < latlong.length ; i++){
        var marker = L.marker(latlong[i]).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup(infowindow[i]).openPopup();

        }
        var polyline = L.polyline(latlong,{color:'red'}).addTo(map);
        <!-- map.addLayer(L.mapquest.trafficLayer());
         <!-- map.addLayer(L.mapquest.incidentsLayer());

         map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/precipitation_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=owmkeyhere"));
    }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line to the [basic MapQuest.js sample](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.0/examples/basic-map/) in the [MapQuest Developer Network](https://developer.mapquest.com/).

map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://tile.openweathermap.org/map/precipitation_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=YOUR_KEY"));

Comment: nothing changed for me let me edit the question and add my code in it so that you can help me out.

Comment: I took your code (removed commented lines) and replaced the MQ and OWM keys and it worked great for me. I had to zoom out a bit to see the overlay tiles from OWM (must be a nice day in NYC) but it all worked great for me. If you're still seeing issues, what errors are you seeing in the console/network tabs?

Comment: amazingly there is no error in my console thats why i am confuse :/

Comment: what are these z x and y ? what values you put in them ?

Comment: Those are placeholders that MapQuest.js fills in for you. Zoom and x/y in the tile grid.

Comment: Are you getting no tiles at all? Error messages? Do you see tiles loading in the network tab?

Comment: kindly check the picture attached

Comment: Hey i just figured it out, i zoomed out the map and the layer was visible .. thanks for tolerating that with me :) 
Is there a way to show weather conditions like http://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=map&cities=true&layer=clouds&lat=30&lon=-20&zoom=3

Comment: Hey i just figured it out, i zoomed out the map and the layer was visible .. thanks for tolerating that with me :) 
Is there a way to show weather conditions like http://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=map&cities=true&layer=clouds&lat=30&lon=-20&zoom=3

Comment: HA, I did that a couple times too. No worries there.

I suspect that map is using Leaflet's divIcon, but I haven't used that yet so I'm not sure. And the data is probably coming from another OWM api.

Comment: I'm guessing the cites within a bounding box api call is on that map mentioned above. https://openweathermap.org/current#rectangle